# How to Generate WOPI Lock Id

Tags: ms-wopi

I am trying to implement WOPI Endpoints, I am not sure whether the lock id should be generated by me and send it in the response header of checkFileInfo response.

Or will the Wopi Client generates the lock Id and send it in the response of Lock

Comment: Are you able to share code you've attempted?  After that, describe what you expected to have happen and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

The `CheckFileInfo` method doesn't require you to return the `X-WOPI-Lock` header. The endpoint should only return information about the capabilities of the WOPI host:

- [`SupportsGetLock`](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-supportsgetlock)
- [`SupportsLocks`](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-supportslocks)

Regarding the `X-WOPI-Lock` header, it's a string of maximum of 1024 ASCII characters generated by WOPI client (Office Web Apps/Office Online Server). 
WOPI host is typically required to return the value when there is a `409` [lock conflict](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/PutFile.html).